# Extracting Announcer Audio Files

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to extract the announcer audio files (I don't know if this is legal or not).

The closest solution I have found is a "[(mini-Tutorial) How to listen to any sound file from LoL (incl. unreleased champions)](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=6920)" however it's a bit too old, that thread started on August 2009 when the game was in beta phase.

Is there an alternative way of doing this besides that post? I really want to listen to the legendary *Penta kill* sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if extracting the files is legal or not, it probably is ok as long as you don't distribute / sell them. Follow these steps at your own risk:

1. Google and download fsbext.zip (I used http://ultrashare.net/hosting/dl/65f2fd1f3d). We will use this to unpack the fsb file that holds all of the sounds
2. Extract fsbext.zip into a folder (for example C:\fsbext)
3. Navigate to the sounds directory of League of Legends (mine is C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_game_client_en_us\managedfiles\0.0.0.20\DATA\Sounds\FMOD, yours may differ)
4. Copy VOBank_en_US.fsb from that directory to your fsbext directory (so that it is in the same folder as fsbext.exe)
5. In the fsbext folder, run the following command in a terminal / command prompt (or create a .bat file in the fsbext folder, copy and paste the command into it and then run the .bat file)

   fsbext.exe -a VOBank_en_US.fsb
6. You'll probably want the files whose names start with "female1_OnChampionPentaKill"

Comment: It worked smoothly, only thing is the audio files are a bit faster than the original sounds! Awarding the bounty in a few, thanks.

Comment: I noticed that. Here's how I fixed it: open the file in Audacity (an open source sound editor, you can use another software if you want) and export it as MP3. You'll need to download an additional DLL file since MP3 exporting isn't included by default. You can find the library needed for MP3 exporting at http://lame.sourceforge.net/. Once you're re-exported the file as MP3 it should play at normal speed.